# Return 0 if there are no string in an array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function here that takes the smallest number in an array.

What I did is that I filtered out only numbers using typeof property and compared the values from Infinity.

Right now, it will return 0 if the array is empty.

However if the array contains only string or other datatypes it will return Infinity.

Here's my codes:

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {

  var smallestNum = Infinity;

  if(arr.length !== 0){
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] < smallestNum){
         smallestNum = arr[i];
     } 
   }
     return smallestNum;
  } 
  return 0;
}


var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['sam', 3, 2, 1]);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```

It must return 0 as well if there are no numbers in the array.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible for the array to contain negative numbers? If not, you can just initialize `smallestNum` to `0` instead of `Infinity`.

Comment: `findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['sam', 3, 2, 1])` is returning `1` for me. Can you provide other test cases?

Comment: Your above example returns 1 not 4.

Comment: @NafiulIslam that's what it should return.. the smallest number among mixed elements. His issue was with input ['a','b'] returning infinity instead of 0.

Comment: var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['sam', 3, 2, 1]);
console.log(output); // --> 4

That's what he said in question, confused a few of us

Comment: Change `return smallestNum;` to `return (smallestNum < Infinity) ? smallestNum : 0;`

Comment: What is the desired behavior if the minimum value in a non-empty array is `Infinity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are special-casing the empty-array case, with the line

```
if(arr.length !== 0){
```

Remove that. Then, if you want to force a result of `Infinity` to `0`, do that at the end.

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {

  var smallestNum = Infinity;

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] < smallestNum){
       smallestNum = arr[i];
    } 
  }

  return isFinite(smallestNum) ? smallestNum : 0;
}
```

However, it is simpler to just filter out the non-numbers using `filter`, and calculate the minimum using `Math.min`. This also makes easier to fix a "bug" in the code above, which is that it will yield `0` for inputs such as `[Infinity, "foo", Infinity]`. I'm not sure whether you prefer to return `0` or `Infinity` in that kind of case. Assuming you do want to return `0`, then

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
  var nums = ...arr.filter(elt => typeof elt === 'number');

  return nums.length ? Math.min(...nums) : 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect. The expected output for input:  [Math.pow(10, 1000)] should be Infinity and this returns 0.

Comment: @gidim Thanks for your comment. It's not clear to me what the OP intends in that case. I've left a comment on his question asking him to clarify that. In the meantime, I've fixed the second solution using `Math.min` to operate as you suggest it should.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably some more elegant ways to solve this. but this fixes your bug.

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {

  var smallestNum = Infinity;
  var numberFound = false

   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] < smallestNum){
         smallestNum = arr[i];
         numberFound = true
     } 
   }
    if(numberFound)
      return smallestNum;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `arr[i] < smallestNum` actually mean here? and why it is required?

Comment: @brk that checks if the current number is smaller than anything else we've seen.

Answer (score 0):

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {

  var smallestNum = Infinity;

  if(arr.length !== 0){
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     if(typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] < smallestNum){
         smallestNum = arr[i];
     } 
   }
     return smallestNum == Infinity? 0 : smallestNum; // if smallest doesn't change return 0
  } 
  return 0;
}


var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['sam', 3, 2, 1]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: this returns the wrong answer for [Math.pow(10, 1000)]. The correct answer is Infinity and your function returns 0...

Comment: Why is the correct answer Infinity? The function is supposed to return the smallest number in the array, how is Infinity the smallest number in Array(Math.pow(10, 1000))?

Answer (score -1):

You could use an odd way of using Array#reduce and Array#filter

First, filter out non-numeric

Second reduce this filtered array, with an initial value of 0 - if the array is zero length, reduce will return 0

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
    var smallestNum = Infinity;
    return arr.filter(item => typeof item == 'number').reduce((min,item) => {
        if(item < smallestNum) smallestNum = item;
        return smallestNum;
    }, 0);
}
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([]));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['1','2','3']));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([1,2,3]));
console.log(findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(['1',2,3]));
```

Comment: Would be rather polite if the downvoter explained the downvote on code that produces the required output as per the request in the question