# Returning the largest Number - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a function here that needs to:

1. Return the largest 'number' in the array.
2. Return 0 if array is empty
3. Return 0 if there are no 'number' in the array.
4. Return the highest negative number if there is one in the array.

Right now, it work on negative numbers and empty array, however for some reason it won't show up the largest number.

Here's my function:

```js
function largestNumber(arr) {

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
      var longestNumber = arr[i];
      if (arr[i] > longestNumber) {
        longestNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }
    return longestNumber;
  }

  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

}

var output1 = largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]);
console.log(output1); // --> must be 5 but display 3 (as the largest)

var output2 = largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]);
console.log(output2); // --> -1

var output3 = largestNumber([]);
console.log(output3); // --> 0

var output4 = largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]);
console.log(output4); // --> must be 5 instead returned undefined
```

Any idea what's causing this? How can I improve my code to get the expected results?

Comment: what was wrong with the [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993083/return-0-if-there-are-no-string-in-an-array-js) answer/question?

Comment: `function largestNumber(arr) { arr = arr.filter(function(n) {return +n === n;}); return arr.length ? Math.max.apply(Math,arr) : 0; }`

Comment: you should `return` after your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two consecutive lines in your function should give you a clue to the problem:

```
var longestNumber = arr[i];
if(arr[i] > longestNumber){
```

You're setting the current number as the longest number, and then comparing it to the same number.

Simply move the first line above outside the `for` loop and default it to zero. You'll also have to move the `return` outside the loop and change your `if` logic slightly to account for all your requirements

```js
function largestNumber(arr) {
   var longestNumber = -Infinity;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
      
      if (arr[i] > longestNumber) {
        longestNumber = arr[i];
      }
    }
  }

  if (longestNumber == -Infinity) {
    longestNumber = 0;
  }  
   return longestNumber;
}

var output1 = largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]);
console.log(output1); // --> must be 5 but display 3 (as the largest)

var output2 = largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]);
console.log(output2); // --> -1

var output3 = largestNumber([]);
console.log(output3); // --> 0

var output4 = largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]);
console.log(output4); // --> must be 5 instead returned undefined
```

Comment: why did it output 0 on the last 3 items?

Comment: @campovski I was updating that as you commented. Well spotted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to "*Return the highest negative number if there is one in the array*", it just returns the highest value. E.g. if *output2* contained a positive number, it should still return -1.

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the array to retain numbers only, then use `Math.max`

```js
function largestNumber(arr) {
    let n = arr.some(e => e<0);
    arr = arr.filter(v => n ? !isNaN(v) && v<0 : !isNaN(v));
    return arr.length === 0 ? 0 : Math.max(...arr);
}

console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]));
console.log(largestNumber([-1, -2]));
console.log(largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]));
console.log(largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]));
console.log(largestNumber([]));
console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]));
console.log(largestNumber([-8, -4, 1, 5]));
```

Comment: And for part 4 of the question?

Comment: @RobG part 2,3 are cleverly taken care of in the short if on the return line of code. +1 for the elegant solution. I didn't see part 4 actually :V

Comment: I don't see "*Return the highest negative number if there is one in the array*", which is different to just returning the largest value.

Comment: Doesn't work for `[-8, -4, 1, 5]`, should return `-4`, returns `5`

Comment: @RobG ahhh. Didn't get that as there's no matching example... One second :)

Comment: @RobG I adapted this question to fully adress this answer in my answer. For the author I don't know if using your answer in my answer is against the policy of StackOverflow. Let me know if it's good for you or not

Comment: @rakwaht no problem, thanks for the attribution. I think mine will be a little faster than your approach, but I can't say for sure. (It does work for part 4 now too)

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(typeof arr[i] ===  'number'){
     var longestNumber = arr[i];
     if(arr[i] > longestNumber){
       longestNumber = arr[i];
     }
```

Here you set `var longestNumber = arr[i]` in each execution of loop which means that at the end the function will return the last element that was a number. Instead, do this:

```
function largestNumber(arr) {
    var longestNumber = -Infinity;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number' && arr[i] > longestNumber) {
            longestNumber = arr[i];
        }
    if (longestNumber > -Infinity) {
        return longestNumber;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the code of @baao from its answer to adress also request number 4

```js
  function largestNumber(arr) {
    arr = arr.filter(v => !isNaN(v));
    negative = arr.filter(v => v < 0);
    return negative.length === 0 ? Math.max(0, ...arr) : Math.min(...arr)
  }

  console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]));
  console.log(largestNumber([-1, -2]));
  console.log(largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]));
  console.log(largestNumber(["word", "up"]));
  console.log(largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]));
  console.log(largestNumber([]));
  console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop the array and check against `undefined` or if the value is greater than the storte value.

```js
function largestNumber(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return typeof a === 'number' && (r === undefined || r < a) ? a : r;
    }, undefined) || 0;
}

console.log(largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]));             //  5
console.log(largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]));                   // -1
console.log(largestNumber([]));                                     //  0
console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5])); //  5
```

With a `for` loop.

```js
function largestNumber(array) {
    var i, longestNumber;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (
            typeof array[i] === 'number' &&
            (longestNumber === undefined || longestNumber < array[i])
        ) {
            longestNumber = array[i];
        }
    }
    return longestNumber || 0;
}

console.log(largestNumber([3, "word", 5, "up", 3, 1]));             //  5
console.log(largestNumber([-1, -5, "word", -3]));                   // -1
console.log(largestNumber([]));                                     //  0
console.log(largestNumber(["word", 3, 5, 3, "wordy", "up", 1, 5])); //  5
```